# How can I make the shiny glow effect around an icon/image? (Pics provided inside)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Before mouse over:

[image] [image]

after mouse over:

[image] [image]

Seems like the glow effect will change its shape according to the image shape.
Is this a NSShadow? How to implement this in code? Any clues or examples? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I could wiht iOS but I think the same applies: set zeo offset for the shadow, blur it enough, give right size and choose white as color.

Comment: Oh nice, I'll post it as an answer then :)

Comment: Just curious, what app did this comes from?  Looks pretty cool. :)

Comment: It comes from Quickpick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could with iOS but I think the same applies:

- set zero offset for the shadow
- blur it enough
- give right size
- and choose white as color.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used in my case, which is practically the same as the other answer but with code:

```
myImage.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
myImage.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
myImage.layer.shadowOpacity = .9;
myImage.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
myImage.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Taken from [here](http://benscheirman.com/2011/09/creating-a-glow-effect-for-uilabel-and-uibutton/)